# How change focused TextBox style on Windows 10 UWP XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How apply a custom style (from a resource) to a TextBox when it has the focus.

My usual solution

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="NoteBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Does not affect the focused or selected state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the Setters in its VisualState. You can get the default template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx).

Just copy it and edit the values in the `Focused` VisualState.